# SSAS Tabular create table from another table with unique column

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have ssas table called orders. I want to extract distinct EmployeeID from the table to create Emp_ID table. when I use

```
=SUMMARIZE(Orders,Orders[EmployeeID])
```

it worked but it add a blank row
Current OUTPUT

[image]

Expected OUTPUT to exclude the blank using DAX

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
=FILTER(
         SUMMARIZE(Orders,Orders[EmployeeID]),
            Orders[EmployeeID]<> BLANK()
)
```